# Simple svg button based on Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Simple svg button based on Snap.svg.

I wrote a test code as below so far.

One obvious problem is, the text and button frame are supposed to be grouped as a single element(at least, I thought so), they react independently depending on where to click.

Any suggestion to improve it? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/yxjKF/31/

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var block = s.rect(50, 50, 100, 100, 20, 20);

block.attr({
    fill: "rgb(236, 240, 241)",
    stroke: "#1f2c39",
    strokeWidth: 3
});

var text = s.text(70, 135, "Hello!");
text.attr({
    'font-size':100
});

block.attr({
    width: (text.node.clientWidth + 50)
})

// group then as a single svg DOM element
var btn1 = s.g(block, text);

btn1.click(function(e)
          {
              $(e.target).css('opacity',0.5);
              setTimeout(function()
                 {               
                     $(e.target).css('opacity',1);
                 },200)
          });
```

Comment: I don't really think this is a place for suggestions... You don't seem to have problems with the code.

Comment: Edited. There is a problem, or problems.

Comment: It is cutting the right hand-side of your button. You have to make your font a little smaller, then you see it: 'font-size':60 - then center the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a reason you are using jquery for the click, as opposed to Raphael. Without knowing more info, I would use a Raphael click handler on the grouped object you have created. So you could do something like this, and then use a simple animate back as well...

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yxjKF/34/)

```
var btn1 = s.g(block, text);

btn1.click( function( ev ) { 
    btn1.attr({ opacity: 0.5 });
    btn1.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500 );
});
```